Extension of a linear isomorphism of graded algebras to $A_{\infty}$-quasi-isomorphism of
Let $(A^{\bullet}, d_A=0, m_A)$ and $(B^{\bullet}, d_B=0, m_B)$ be two graded associative algebras, where $d_A$ and $d_B$ are the corresponding differentials and $m_A$ and $m_B$ denote the respective multiplication operations. Assume that there exists an isomorphism of (trivially differential) graded morphisms
$$f_1: (A^{\bullet}, d_A=0)\cong (B, d_B=0).$$
Then, in particular, $f_1$ is a trivial quasi-isomorphism of cochain complexes as $fd_A=d_Bf$ is trivially satisfied. Then, according to Proposition $2.2$ in Bernhard Keller's notes on $A_{\infty}$-algebras (https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bernhard.keller/publ/ainffun.pdf), the (trivial differential) graded module $(B^{\bullet}, d_B=0)$ possesses an $A_{\infty}$-structure $\{m_i\}_{i\in\mathbb Z_{+}}$ such that $f_1$ extends to an $A_{\infty}$-quasi-isomorphism
$$\{f_i\}:~(A, d_A=0, m_A)\xrightarrow{A_{\infty}-\textrm{quasi-iso}}(B, \{m_i\}).$$
Bernhard Keller does not give however the structure maps $m_i$ on $B^{\bullet}$! I would like to know how the $m_i$'s are constructed and also I would like to have a reference to the result (Proposition $2.2$) Keller uses.

A non-exhaustive list of references containing explicit formulas for that result are, in chronological order:

T. V. Kadeishvili, On the theory of homology of fiber spaces, (Russian) International Topology Conference (Moscow State Univ., Moscow, 1979). Uspekhi Mat. Nauk 35 (1980), no. 3 (213), 183–188. Translated in Russ. Math. Surv. 35 (1980), no. 3 (238) 231–211
S. A. Merkulov, "Strong homotopy algebras of a Kähler manifold." Int. Math. Res. Not. 1999, No. 3, 153--164 (1999)  (see Section 3).
Markl, Martin, "Transferring A∞
(strongly homotopy associative) structures." Čadek, Martin (ed.), The proceedings of the 25th winter school “Geometry and physics”, Srní, Czech Republic, January 15–22, 2006. Palermo: Circolo Matemático di Palermo. Supplemento ai Rendiconti del Circolo Matemático di Palermo. Serie II 79, 139-151 (2006).
Lu, D.-M.; Palmieri, J. H.; Wu, Q.-S.; Zhang, J. J., "A-infinity structure on Ext-algebras." J. Pure Appl. Algebra 213, No. 11, 2017-2037 (2009). (see Section 2)


From what I read I infer that Keller's results in his notes is false! There is no $A_{\infty}$-structure on $V$ so that there is an $A_{\infty}$-quasi-isomorphism $A\to V$. It is exactly the other way around! The quasi isomorphism $A\to V$ defines a homotopy retract $V\to A$ which defines an $A_{\infty}$ structure on $A$, not on $V$, so that there is an $A_{\infty}$-quasi-isomorphism $A\to V$. Exactly the opposite of what Keller claims. The initial $A_{\infty}$ structure must be given to $V$, not to $A$!

Proposition 2.2 in Keller's notes asserts that any chain complex $V$ that is quasi-isomorphic to a differential graded algebra $A$ can be endowed with an $A_\infty$-algebra structure together with an $A_\infty$-quasi-isomorphism extending the linear quasi-isomorphism of the underlying complex. This is correct, and it is the same claim that more or less are in the references I gave. The idea is that if two chain complexes are quasi-isomorphic (i.e., they have the same homology) and one of them has an algebra structure, then you can induce an "equivalent" $A_\infty$-structure on the other.

If you write it down concretely what you say in your post, you will see that Keller's maps are the wrong way. A quasi-isomorphism of chain complexes of vector spaces $i:(A, d_A)\to (V, d_V)$ fits in a homotopy retract $p: V\to A$ with section $i$ such that $i\circ p=d_Vh+hd_V$, where $h$ is a homotopy. If $V$ has an $A_{\infty}$-structure, one can transfer this structure onto $A$, so that the quasi-isomorphism $i$ extends to an $A_{\infty}$-quasi-isomorphism $A\to V$. Keller has messed up which complex should have the initial $A_{\infty}$-structure. It is not $A$ but $V$.

I don't see why the maps are in the wrong direction. In any case, it does not really matter: a quasi-isomorphism $A\to V$ is simply a chain map inducing an isomorphism in homology.  Over a field, this quasi-isomorphism has a quasi-inverse $V\to A$, i.e., there is a quasi-isomorphism in the other direction. So, you can write $V$ as a retract of $A$ using your notation and you have already switched the maps around. I think it is a good idea to have in mind the example where $A$ is a dg algebra and $V$ its homology, everything over a field.

The way Keller's proposition is written down, is simply outrageously confusing if not completely false. If by a quasi-isomorphism $A\to V$, Keller actually means implicitly the quasi-inverse $V\to A$, then this quasi-isomorphism becomes part of a homotopy retract $A\to V$ which equips $V$ with an $A_{\infty}$-structure. However, even in that case, the homotopy retract $A\to V$ does not imply an $A_{\infty}$-quasi-isomorphism $A\to V$ but an $A_{\infty}$-quasi-isomorphism  $V\to A$. This is by the way precisely Kadeishvili's theorem about homology of a dg-algebra.

If Keller works with the quasi-isomorphism $A\to V$, this implies a homotopy retract $V\to A$. So, by the homotopy transfer theorem, you can only transfer an $A_{\infty}$-structure from $V$ to $A$, not the other way around, as Keller claims. After the transfer of $A_{\infty}$-structure from $V$ to $A$, the homotopy retract $V\to A$ implies again by the homotopy transfer theorem an $A_{\infty}$-quasi-iso $A\to V$.  So, no matter with which quasi-iso you start, $A\to V$ or $V\to A$, Keller has messed up either the transfer of $A_{\infty}$ structures or the direction of $A_{\infty}$-quasi-iso's.

I don't agree with your assertion. Where exactly in Keller's notes does he claim that $A$ is a retract of $V$? I don't see it. If you look after Proposition 2.2, he exhibits $V=H_*(A)$ as a retract of $A$, not the other way around.

I do not know what you mean by "$A$ is a retract of $V$". A homotopy retract is the following data: $p: (A, d_A)\to (V, d_V)$, $i: (V, d_V)\to (A, d_A)$ are chain maps such that $i$ is a quasi-iso and $1-i\circ p=d_Ah+hd_A$, where $h$ is a homotopy of $A$. If $A$ has $A_{\infty}$-structure, we use $i$ and $p$ to transfer the $A_{\infty}$-structure on $A$ on the chain complex $V$. After we do that, this yields an $A_{\infty}$-quasi-iso $F:V\to A$ with $F_1=i$. This is the correct way according to all sources you gave in the above, in particular according to Kadeishvilli.

I think we don't quite understand each other; maybe I just missunderstood your objections. So I'll leave it here :-) Anyway, I am glad that you understand it now.

Thanks for the references and the discussion.
